# Rule for Free Shipping in a range of postcode/zip don't working

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, free-shipping

In cart price rule, the rule bellow doesn't works, I followed the official doc: https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/shipping/shipping-free.html which I was able to get free shipping using another rule (ex. subtotal >100).

[image: Free Shipping rule]

If I have only the **equals or great than** rule, it works with postcode >= than the wanted value, the same happens when I leave only the **equals or less than**, but never with both rules

Is that a bug? I'm using Magento 2.4.2

How can I debug theses rules?

Is there a better way to achieve it? I was thinking about use flat rate but the native module don't works with postcode range.

I could create a module for it, but seems a workaround, anyway I'm not expert with magento shipping workflow, (suggestions?)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think zip code ranges are not supported. You might want to look into Matrix Rate plugins that do zip code ranges. Something like this: https://webshopapps.com/ca/matrixrate-shipping-extension.html

Comment: You can only do NOT this or THIS zip code in standard Magento.